# AWS Glue job optimization for long running job

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am running AWS Glue pyspark script which reads data from multiple tables(running query which has multiple joins using redshift jdbc connection). I have developed complex query and it returns around 500M records. Using 20 DPUs and type is G.2X

```
 df = spark.read \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .option("url", url) \
            .option("query", query) \
            .option("fetchsize", "100000") \
            .option("user", user) \
            .option("password", pwd) \
            .load()
```

Once I read data from redshift table and applying some transformation and writing back to redshift table.

While writing data to tables its taking long time to insert data into table.

I tried to use bulkSize to use parallel inserts but still I don't see any improvement(somewhere I red that bulkSize will initiate concurrent jobs to improve the insert process). But at the sametime I don't see concurrent jobs initiated with bulkSize option in write_dynamic_frame_from_jdbc_conf(also not sure how it will initiate multiple concurrent jobs)

```
datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_jdbc_conf(frame=df,
                                                          catalog_connection=connection,
                                                          connection_options={
                                                                      "dbtable": "table",
                                                                      "database": "database",
                                                                      "bulkSize" : "7"}, redshift_tmp_dir="s3://bucket/temp_dir,                               transformation_ctx="datasink" )
```

Please guide/suggest on how to improve the performance of the glue job.

Really appreciate for your help.

Thanks,
Babu

Comment: Have you compared performance against running the same thing using a SQL [CTAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CTAS_examples.html) statement over a JDBC connection? You can sometimes optimize SQL by looking at the [Query Plan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-analyzing-the-query-plan.html)

Comment: Yes. I ran CTAS and its finishing in 25min where as my job running for 2 and half hours.

Comment: If you are reading from and writing to Redshift, why would you use Glue instead of CTAS?

Comment: I need to apply some transformations and so I am using Glue